# Requests and connections double on node 4.1.2

Tags: node.js

We're currently in the process of updating from node 0.10 to node 4.1.2 and we're seeing some weird patterns. The number of connections to our postgres database doubles[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT4YN.png) and we're seeing the same pattern with requests to external services[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DKyu.png). We are running a clustered app running the native cluster API and the number of workers is the same for both versions.

I'm failing to understand why upgrading the runtime language would apparently change application behaviour by doubling requests to external services.

[image: Postgres connections]
[image: External requests]

Comment: Which node package are you using to access postgres?

Comment: `pg` v4.4.1. I also opened an [issue on their repo](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/871) but I don't think the problem is coming from there.

Comment: They released 4.4.2 to cater for some issues around Node 4.x support. Have you tried it yet? What makes you think the problem isn't coming from there? I would suspect the pg package first.

Comment: According to `pg`'s author nothing has changed in terms of connection pooling for a long time. Also the 2nd graph I posted is of external HTTP requests which also seem to double and have nothing to do with postgres. I'm now suspecting the app clustering but no evidence anything is "doubled" right now.

Comment: Your question requires a unique research. It is not likely the issue is known to anyone, especially considering just how fresh NodeJS 4.x is.

Comment: You're probably right. I was hoping someone would have seen this scenario already and could help.

Comment: It's interesting really and a good research object. But please bear in mind that this is somewhat anticipated since between `0.10.0` and `4.2` lie 2.5 years. The language has changed a lot. Also this is a [really good read](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.10-and-v4)   as a starting point.

Comment: @chris911 You have any updates on this?

Comment: Not yet. Will probably deploy once more next week on node latest.

Comment: Have you considered that the change may be the way New Relic is tracking things in Node? I would reach out to them. The New Relic agent hooks in at a very low-level and could be causing side effects.

Comment: Yeah that was one of my first idea. When I posted this New Relic didn't officially support Node 4. Numbers were the same when they released a client with official support for Node 4 though. Months later we figured that the number of DB connections on Node 4 is actually the expected number. For some reasons it seems with 0.10 we were underusing our ressources and available connections. As for the number of HTTP requests to external service we just assumed it was a change in the tracking code and moved on. All is fine and we've been on node 4 for a couple months now.

Comment: You may have been affected by a change that landed in 0.12.0. From https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.12.0/: "HTTP maxSockets are no longer limited to 5. The default is now set to Infinity with the developer and the operating system given control over how many simultaneous connections an application can keep open to a given host."

Answer (score 1):

One of the interesting things I've noticed with 0.12 and 4.x is the change in garbage collection.  I've not used the pg module before so I don't know internally how it maintains it's pools of if it would be affected by memory or garbage collection.  If you haven't defined default memory setting for node you could try giving that a shot and see if you see any other results.

`node --max_old_space_size <some sane value in MB>`

Comment: After more investigation I doubt the problem is coming from postgres and the connection pool. What is worrying is really the number of outgoing HTTP requests which lies in the application logic and doesn't use any external lib.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar, but I was getting double file writes. I don't know your exact case, but I've seen a scenario where requests could almost exactly double.

in the update to 4.1.2, **process.send** and **child.send** has gone from **synchronous to asynchronous**.

I found an issue like this:

```
var child = fork('./request.js');
var test = {};

child.send(small request);
child.send(large request);
child.on('response', function (val) {
    console.log('small request came back: ' + val);
    test = val;
});

if(!test){
   //retry request
} ...
```

So where as previously the blocking sends has allowed this code to work, the non-blocking version assumes an error has occurred and retries. No error actually occurred, so double the requests come in.

Comment: Interesting. We're using [throng](https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng/blob/master/lib/throng.js) to do clustering and fork the whole app. There's no retry logic in there.